# Change the file reference in a formula using the content of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need help with a formula (or macro) please.
On the printscreen below ColA and Row1 are copied in via a macro and cells c2 down and right are formulas.
The problem I have is when Row1 is copied in next time the project names might change (say a new one called "100 Project") and I will need to change the filename in the formulas in C5 onwards.
I don't want to use INDIRECT as I can't have 70 or so files open.

Is there a formula I can use please or does anyone have a macro that'll do the job?

**[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue83t.png)**

Comment: Either use INDIRECT or VBA, there is no other solution. And if you want to use VBA, this site is not the right place to just ask for code; this is for Q&A. Why do you think INDIRECT would require you to have 70 files open, anyway?

Comment: There is the INDIRECT.EXT solution from the free third-party MoreFunc add-on library but it would have to be installed on every machine opening the workbook (and I cannot remember what its current state with 64-bit Excel is).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) does not work on closed workbooks and it seems that there are 70-odd external workbooks referenced from those formulas.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - yes in that case to pull data you would need a VBA solution.

Comment: I'm unclear on why the macro mentioned in *"...are copied in via a macro and cells c2 down and right are formulas."* does not adjust the formulas to suit the new data.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Copying & pasting is about my limits on macros. Replacing text is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Show us a full circle of what you want to use, what you want to do with it and what the end result should look like. (you can reference the screenshot provided) as I'm not quite clear of want you want to do and don't want to guess.

In any case:
=CELL("filename",A1) should help you with current file name however you rename the document you work on.

Other than that you can import however many filenames you have on a list without needing to open them. We will expand on that should it be needed.

PS Based on updated info:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",$C$3,"'","!","A",ROW()))
The reference to make that formula work is C3

This is integrated instead of your
" 'g:\it\capex\2015 etc etc tec ... Plan'!$B$20:$B$119   "

C3="C:\folder\[filename.xlsx]sheet name"
```

(derived by formula or however you want - the result shows the address)

If you want to put in the sheet name independently or more flexibly simply add one more ,references for it to the concatenation.

Either adjust the formula to accommodate your C3 or adjust your c3 to accommodate the formula its fairly simple = you can do it more easily when you remove the INDIRECT and see what remains as text. Get the correct text running through that and you can need correct reference. You can use the general idea to create dynamic address lists that you can reference from 1 location. Further more vba can pull names from directories so you can compile an active list, leaving you with little to no manual work... Yes - most people usually frown upon crafting location addresses in formulas and usually tell you to reorganize your work files, but some times its necessary to access files ad-hoc on value based references.

Comment: On the first printscreen Col A is pasteded in from the "Resource" tab, C1 right is pasted in from the "Project List" tab, C2 & c3 are lookups to Project List, C4 right & B5 down are simple count formulas.

Comment: Try again! ......On the printscreen Col A is pasteded in from the "Resource" tab, C1 right is pasted in from the "Project List" tab, C2 & c3 are lookups to Project List, C4 right & B5 down are simple count formulas. This tab tells us who is forecast to be on how many projects.The trouble is that the formulas in C5 down & right will need to change every time this is run as the Project List is pretty fluid. (this data is then transfered on to the "Resource by Week" tab and the formulas will need to be changed on there as well - happy days!)

Comment: What is preventing you from using indirect?

Comment: Indirect needs the target files open and there are about 70 project files so it's just not practical.

Comment: You can check out the revised answer

Comment: Hi Helena, I'm being dragged off to a meeting so will have another go tomorrow but I'm pretty sure I've tried this and it didn't work. Thanks, Paul

Comment: Have fun - it works if you get the address correctly in the concatenation. I just pried it off existing files i use. Its just easy to mess up - 1 symbol off in the concatenation and the formula breaks without giving you a hint that its broken

Comment: Meetings meetings!......Thank you everyone, I'll try fixing this over the weekend. Paul